# why php-fpm ignores error_log option?

Tags: php

I have a clean Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit VM with latest php-fpm installed (php 5.6.11-1 ubuntu3.1). Surprisingly, if I supply a log file name via command-line it will still use path that was specified during compilation:

```
$ php5-fpm -d "error_log=syslog"
ERROR: failed to open error_log (/var/log/php5-fpm.log)
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

**Update 1**

Result is absolutely the same if I specify `error_log` in non-default configuration file, ex `php-fpm.conf`:

```
error_log = syslog
php_admin_value[error_log] = syslog
```

and by running `php-fpm` via:

```
php5-fpm -c php-fpm.conf
```

Comment: Any chance you can simply change the error facility in the .conf file, rather than passing it as an argument to the binary? Edit: the `-d` option is for configuring `.ini` entries for PHP language behaviour. It's not for configuration options of the fastcgi process manager. It means you can't use it to change the logging facility.

Comment: @Mjh Thanks for your suggestion! I have tried it and updated my question.